# How to prove $\frac{m(r_1 + r_2 + \cdots + r_m - 1)!}{r_1! r_2! \cdots r_m!}$ is an integer?

Tags: combinatorics, integers, symmetric-polynomials

> I want to prove the following is an integer
>
> **$\frac{m(r_1 + r_2 + \cdots + r_m - 1)!}{r_1! r_2! \cdots r_m!}$**
>
> where $r_i$ are non-negative integers and they satisfy $r_1 + 2r_2 + \cdots +mr_m = m$.

Actually, those are the coefficients of the relation between the power sums and the elementary symmetric polynomials in the [Newton-Girard identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

How can I see the above combinatoric quantity is an integer?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{m(r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_m-1)!}{r_1!r_2!\cdots r_m!}$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{i(r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_m-1)!}{r_1!r_2!\cdots(r_i-1)!\cdots r_m!}.$$
Each term of the above sum is an integer, so is the sum.

Comment: Wow! This is really clever!

Comment: What is represented in the denominator in the last term? Does it mean it excludes $$r_i!$$?

Comment: @justhalf, it is $(r_i-1)!$, because $r_i$ in numerator gets cancelled.